# файлы в каталогах и подкаталогах

Tags: c, linux

Нужно найти все файлы в каталоге и во всех подкаталогах и копировать в каталог Dir.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Для чтения каталогов в стандартной библиотеке C есть функции описанные в заголовочном файле `dirent.h`. Следующий фрагмент делает просмотр одного каталога.

```
#include <dirent.h>

...

    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *ep;

    dp = opendir(path);
    if (!dp) {
        /* Ошибка открытия, возможно нет прав, или это не каталог, или что-то ещё, можно уточнить через errno */
       ...
    }
    while ((ep = readdir(dp))) {
        if (!strcmp(ep->d_name, "..") || !strcmp(ep->d_name, ".")) continue;
        /* делаем с именем что-то дальше */
        ...
    }
    closedir(dp);
```

Перед копированием стоит проверить различные ситуации, например если файл назначения уже существует и это ссылка на исходный файл, или если исходный файл - устройство, fifo - файл, сокет или символическая ссылка.

Все эти проверки делает утилита `cp`, но при рекурсивном обходе она копирует дерево каталогов в дерево, а не в один каталог. Если вы хотите написать копирование сами, стоит ознакомиться с [исходниками `cp`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/cp.c;h=8fb5e444fbaf529c19b3d9ff92c3928302e39118;hb=master) или с более простым вариантом в [busybox](https://busybox.net/source.html).

Так же можно сделать рекурсивный обход с помощью утилиты `find`.